# I can not understand CSS: first-child

Tags: html, css

I have problem with first-child selector. In code I have two div (this same class), img (in every) and p (in every). When i type in CSS .div-class:first-child {margin:10}, in the p a margin is added and only in first div.

First ask: why margin was not added to img (first element in div)
Second ask: why margin is added only first div (second have this same class name)

```html
<section class="section-offer">

    <div class="section-offer-single">
        <img src="images/pizza.png" alt="Pizza">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section-offer-single">
        <img src="images/pizza.png" alt="Pizza">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

```css
.section-offer-single:first-child{
  margin: 0px 0px 130px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-child` is a selector used to select an element that *is* a first child, not the first child of that element.

To get the first children of the `.section-offer-single` elements, use the selector:

```
.section-offer-single > :first-child
```

This also explains why only the first `.section-offer-single` had the styles applied to it -- this is because  *it* is the (only) first child of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

> why margin was not added to img (first element in div)

The selector is `.section-offer-single:first-child`. While `:first-child` matches the `<img>`, `.section-offer-single` **does not**.

> why margin is added only first div (second have this same class name)

The second `<div>` matches `.section-offer-single` but doesn't match `:first-child`.

---

A selector only matches if the **whole** selector matches. (Keeping in mind that `,` groups multiple selectors together on one rule-set).